# Unable to open form with frame in designer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a frame:

```
TfrmMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  ...
end;
```

Which is placed on my main form as follows:

```
interface

uses Myframe;

type
  TfrmMyMainForm = class(TForm)
    FmyFrm: TfrmMyFrame;
    ...
  end;
```

In design time I am unable to open my main form, unless I open the frame in the designer. I always have to open my frame form before I can open the main form. Please note that I am talking about design time only. Is this correct behavior? If not, how can I correct it? I am using XE5.

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Please include more detail than "I am unable to open my main form". What exactly happens.

Comment: What happens when you try to open the main form without having opened the frame form? Please describe exactly what happens. Please do so in an edit to the question.

Comment: Is the frame unit added to your project?

Comment: No my frame window was not added to the project. After added it the main form opens without any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Frames must be included in the project for the designer to add them to or display them on a form. They can still be dynamically added to a form at runtime.

If you examine the dfm of your form you will notice frames are added using the word `inline`. This is translated by the VCL component streaming system to the enum value `TComponentState.csInline` and is used to indicate that the component is a top-level container that can be embedded into a form.

The form designer uses the same component streaming system as is used at runtime. My guess is it only parses forms and frames that are currently loaded into the IDE's internal cache. This would explain why you could open the form if you opened the frame first. By adding the frame to the project it will be loaded into a cache when the project is opened in the IDE.

> *Fun Fact*
>
> There is a trick used by IDE extension programmers to design forms that inherit from `TDockForm`, which is an Open Tools API
>   component that is only supplied in a precompiled binary package (no
>   source and no dfm). By implementing a *fake* `TDockForm` in a dummy
>   project that is part of the same project group as the descendent the
>   IDE can be fooled into loading the fake. This trick relies on the same
>   behavior you discovered by accident.